Run SQL database Select Query on the Azure IaaS SQL Server and send the output to CSV
Run SQL query on the database which resides in Azure IaaS server and send the output to CSV format.
I tried with couple of options but didnot get the desired output so looking for some help here .
        $scriptCode = @'
        $query = "use test_MO; 
        SELECT * from FROM licenses"
        $sql_job = Invoke-Sqlcmd  -ServerInstance $servername -Query "$Query"
        $sql_job
'@
        $runquery = Invoke-AzVMRunCommand -ResourceGroupName $ServerRGName  -VMName $ServerName -CommandId 'RunPowerShellScript' -ScriptPath                        "sqllicensereport.ps1" -Parameter @{servername = $servername}



Run SQL database Select Query on the Azure IaaS SQL Server and send the output to CSV

Try with the below code to send the query output to CSV. The output has stored in Azure Blob Storage Container as shown in the output below.
$serverName = "pbserver1.database.windows.net"
$databaseName = "db1"
$username = "pbadmin1"
$password = "<password>"

$query = @"
USE $databaseName;
SELECT * FROM licenses;
"@

$connectionString = "Server=$serverName;Database=$databaseName;User ID=$username;Password=$password;"

# Install SqlServer module if not already installed
Install-Module -Name SqlServer -Force -AllowClobber -Scope CurrentUser -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

# Import the SqlServer module
Import-Module -Name SqlServer -ErrorAction Stop

# Execute the SQL query
try {
    $result = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $serverName -Database $databaseName -Username $username -Password $password -Query $query -ErrorAction Stop

    # Convert the result to CSV string
    $csvString = $result | ConvertTo-Csv -NoTypeInformation

    # Upload the CSV file to Azure Blob Storage
    $storageAccountName = "pbazst1"
    $containerName = "firstcont" 
    $blobName = "output.csv"

    $storageAccountKey = "<storage key>" 
    $context = New-AzStorageContext -StorageAccountName $storageAccountName -StorageAccountKey $storageAccountKey

    Set-AzStorageBlobContent -File $localFilePath -Container $containerName -Blob $blobName -Context $context -Force

    Write-Host "File uploaded successfully to Azure Blob Storage."
} catch {
    Write-Host "Error executing SQL query: $_"
}

Output:


It looks to be, work for Paas database but I'm querying with azure Iaas SQL machine.

Could you refer to this doc once, for more info on Azure IAAS SQL.
